# Getting '"Contract" hit an invalid opcode while deploying.' when deploying to BNB smartchain using Truffle

Tags: deployment, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, migrate

I have deployed an NFT contract to sepolia testnet without any issues. I am now attempting to deploy the contract to BNBtestnet. I ran into the above error. Here is my truffle-config:

```
 require('dotenv').config();
 const { GETBLOCK_API_KEY,INFURA_API_KEY, MNEMONIC } = process.env;

 const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {


  networks: {

     development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
     },

    sepolia: {
       provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, INFURA_API_KEY),
       network_id: 11155111,       // Goerli's id
      gas: 5500000,
     },

     BNBTestnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s3.binance.org:8545`),
      network_id: 97,       // 
     gas: 5500000,
    },

    BNBMainnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org`),
      network_id: 56,       // 
     gas: 5500000,
    },

  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters, etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.20",     
    }
  },

  plugins: ['truffle-plugin-verify'],
  api_keys: {
    etherscan: 'BUG238UXURBAF9HE4AAZ68DWAW73PNHI4P',
  },
};
```

I tried re-installing Truffle and changing the RPC endpoint, but neither helped. To see if it was something specific with the testnet I tried deploying to BNB smartchain, this caused the same error.

Comment: did you add BNB test network to metamask and when you deployed you weere connected to BNB testwork

Comment: I deployed directly from Truffle, that shouldn't matter. I

Answer (score 0):

binance test chain does not support solidity version 20 at this moment, you can downgrade solidity to 0.8.19 version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).